# Youtrack, get list value some fields

Tags: javascript, workflow, youtrack

I want to get a list of all the values that are now available in the field State, for example, that is, approximately so `['Open', 'Closed', 'Hold']`

I try

```
var arrSprint = issue.fields['State'];
console.log(arrSprint);
```

But this command outputs to me characteristics this fileds

`"foregroundColor": "#444",
"presentation": "Open",
"colorIndex": "0",
"description": "null",
"name": "Open",`

Answer (score 0):

Possible values can be retrieved from the respective ProjectCustomField. To get a ProjectCustomField, either call issue.project.findFieldByName('State'), or better add a requirement like
State: {
  type: entities.State.fieldType
}
which will allow you to access the ProjectCustomField via ctx.State.